# How to flatten objects in mongodb automatically

Tags: json, mongodb, set, flatten, json-flattener

I have some data that needs to be flattened, which means go from this format:

```
"user": {
      "id": "AEC77ACD-02D3-0057-842F-DC23D6312389",
      "name": "Eliza Chukiua",
      "email": "eliza.chukiua@booking.com",
      "group": "SSO",
      "externalId": "eliza.chukiua@booking.com"
```

To this format:

```
    "user_email": "eliza.chukiua@booking.com",
    "user_externalId": "eliza.chukiua@booking.com",
    "user_group": "SSO",
    "user_id": "AEC77ACD-02D3-0057-842F-DC23D6312389",
    "user_name": "Eliza Chukiua"
```

To do this, the code is

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      user_id: "$user.id",
      user_email: "$user.email",
      user_name: "$user.name",
      user_externalId: "$user.externalId",
      user_group: "$user.group"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "user"
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

The problem is that I have more fields I have to flatten and they not always are on the data set, which means I need a way to flatten all the crap fields, even if I don't know their names. That is because new crappy fields can be created and I have no way to know every single crap field name.

What I am using to test it is this mongodb playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXJWzKIUDob, feel free to play around.

How do I flatten every crappy field automatically, without having to $set every single one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Query1

- general case that you dont know which fields have as value documents and you dont know the fields in the nested document
- same as Query2, but doesn't require to know which fields needs flattening, you dont give the "user" for example
- it does nested reduce, to reduce the `$$ROOT` also

*works for deep nesting also, but you have to repeat it, like do one update for level 1 nesting, second update for level2 nesting etc
i will produce `field1_field2_field3 : value` etc

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=636914db424f6130d7f1215b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"root": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$root",
        "initialValue": {},
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$value",
             {"$cond": 
               [{"$not": [{"$eq": [{"$type": "$$this.v"}, "object"]}]},
                 {"$arrayToObject": [[["$$this.k", "$$this.v"]]]},
                 {"$let": 
                   {"vars": 
                     {"nested_field": "$$this.k", "nested_value": "$$this.v"},
                    "in": 
                     {"$reduce": 
                       {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$$this.v"},
                        "initialValue": {},
                        "in": 
                         {"$mergeObjects": 
                           ["$$value",
                             {"$arrayToObject": 
                               [[[{"$concat": ["$$nested_field", "_", "$$this.k"]},
                                    "$$this.v"]]]}]}}}}}]}]}}}}}])
```

Query2

- the above is big query but if you know the names of the fields that need flattening for example "user" field it can be much smaller
- you can repeat the code for any other field, or genetate it dynamically for all fields
- makes user an array to allow to process the field names as values
- reduces to make them document again, after it concats the parent field name string to the subfield name
- finally add those fields into root and `$unset` the field "user"

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63690f16424f6130d7f12159)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"user": {"$objectToArray": "$user"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"user": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$user",
        "initialValue": {},
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$value",
             {"$arrayToObject": 
               [[[{"$concat": ["user_", "$$this.k"]}, "$$this.v"]]]}]}}}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$user", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$unset": ["user"]}])
```

**As Update**
If you need this pipeline in update you can use it like    `updateMany({},[...stages...])`